# Code to follow monthly advance and retreat of ice/snow Google earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I intend to develop a code in GEE to identify areas with snow/ice cover and quantify its advance and retraction over the months, obtaining the mean, median, maximum and minimum value, standard deviation and, subsequently, a chart containing this information and images for each month with the data must be prepared. However, I got the following error:

> Line 52: collection.mean is not a function

How it can be solved?

The code:

```
// Carregar as coleções de imagens do Landsat 4, 5 e 8
var landsat4 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT04/C01/T1_SR");
var landsat5 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR");
var landsat8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR");

// Filtrar as imagens por data e porcentagem de nuvens
var startDate = '2000-01-01';
var endDate = '2023-12-31';
var cloudThreshold = 0;

var filtered4 = landsat4.filterDate(startDate, endDate)
                        .filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUD_COVER', cloudThreshold));
var filtered5 = landsat5.filterDate(startDate, endDate)
                        .filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUD_COVER', cloudThreshold));
var filtered8 = landsat8.filterDate(startDate, endDate)
                        .filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUD_COVER', cloudThreshold));

// Combinar as coleções em uma única coleção
var merged = ee.ImageCollection(filtered4.merge(filtered5).merge(filtered8));

// Definir uma função para calcular o índice de neve normalizado (NDSI)
var ndsi = function(image) {
  return image.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B6']).rename('NDSI');
};

// Aplicar a função NDSI à coleção de imagens
var ndsiCollection = merged.map(ndsi);

// Definir um limiar para classificar a neve e o gelo
var snowThreshold = 0.4;

// Definir uma função para criar uma máscara binária de neve e gelo
var snowMask = function(image) {
  var mask = image.gte(snowThreshold).rename('snow_mask');
  return image.addBands(mask);
};

// Aplicar a função de máscara à coleção de imagens
var maskedCollection = ndsiCollection.map(snowMask);

// Agrupar as imagens por mês e ano
var byMonthYear = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  maskedCollection.map(function(image) {
    var month = image.date().get('month');
    var year = image.date().get('year');
    return image.set('month', month, 'year', year);
  }).distinct('month')
);

// Definir uma função para reduzir as imagens por mês e ano
var reduceByMonthYear = function(collection) {
var mean = ee.Image(collection.mean()).rename('mean');
  var median = collection.median().rename('median');
  var min = collection.min().rename('min');
  var max = collection.max().rename('max');
  var stdDev = collection.reduce(ee.Reducer.stdDev()).rename('stdDev');
  return mean.addBands(median).addBands(min).addBands(max).addBands(stdDev);
};

// Aplicar a função de redução à coleção de imagens
var reducedCollection = byMonthYear.map(reduceByMonthYear);

// Exibir a coleção de imagens reduzidas no mapa
Map.addLayer(reducedCollection, {bands: 'mean', min: 0, max: 1}, 'Snow/Ice Cover');

// Extrair os valores das bandas de estatística para um gráfico
var statsChart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: reducedCollection.select(['mean', 'median', 'min', 'max', 'stdDev']),
  region: Map.getBounds(),
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 30,
}).setOptions({
  title: 'Snow/Ice Cover Statistics by Month and Year',
  vAxis: {title: 'NDSI'},
  hAxis: {title: 'Date'},
});

// Adicionar o gráfico ao painel
print(statsChart);
```

Comment: Your code has a lot of issues. First of all, you are working at global scale an this fact is producing a lot of images (224476) for your dates range. So, it is convenient to define a **roi** area for filtering by bounds. After that, it can be debugged that your **byMonthYear** function won't work because your previous images don't have a "system:time_start".